# Delete all rows excepts the ones returned from the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've mistakenly been inserting duplicates into a DB. I've built up the query that returns back all of the row ids I want to keep.  How do I delete the rows not given in the query. Can you please include the full query in your answer.

```
select min(matches.`id`)from matches
where  (stream_match_time, track_match_time, user_id, track_id ) in (
  select stream_match_time, track_match_time, user_id, track_id 
  from   matches
  group  by stream_match_time, track_match_time, user_id, track_id 
  having count(*) > 1
)
group  by stream_match_time, track_match_time, user_id, track_id
```

Comment: Have you tried `DELETE FROM matches WHERE matches.id NOT IN (your query)`?

Comment: I tried that and I get "You can't specify target table 'matches' for update in FROM clause".  If I run "select * FROM matches WHERE matches.id NOT IN" I do get back the results I want to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
delete from matches where id not in (...)
```

but you must nest your query one level deeper like this:

```
delete from matches
where id not in (
  select id from (
    select min(id) id from matches
    where  (stream_match_time, track_match_time, juked_user_id, track_id ) in (
      select stream_match_time, track_match_time, juked_user_id, track_id 
      from   matches
      group  by stream_match_time, track_match_time, juked_user_id, track_id 
      having count(*) > 1
    )
    group by stream_match_time, track_match_time, juked_user_id, track_id 
  ) t
)
```

I think that your query does not need 2 levels of aggregation, so try also this:

```
delete from matches
where id not in (
  select id from (
    select min(id) id 
    from   matches
    group by stream_match_time, track_match_time, juked_user_id, track_id 
    having count(*) > 1
  ) t
)
```

Comment: For some reason no rows are effected when I try that.  I can use the query below, but can not use it with DELETE.    SELECT * FROM matches WHERE matches.id NOT IN (

Comment: I don't have your actual data so I can't say. Try my 2nd simplified query.